# Realm read data with relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, electron, realm

I'm working on realm to make it work offline as local db in Electron. Now I want to make join(aggregation), so I defined a relationship between two schema's but then the data is not getting synced. It would be great to get help.

Here's my schema:

```
const articleMetaSchema = {
    name: 'articlemeta',
    properties: {
      _id: 'objectId?',
      catalog_id: 'objectId?',
      content: 'objectId?',
      createdAt: 'date?',
      description: 'string?',
      main_image_url: 'string?',
      origin_type: 'string?',
      pub_date: 'date?',
      publication: 'objectId?',
      sub_title: 'string?',
      title: 'string?',
      updatedAt: 'date?',
      url: 'string?'
    },
    primaryKey: '_id'
  }

const articleSchema = {
    name: 'article',
    properties: {
      _id: 'objectId?',
      active_search: 'bool?',
      article_meta: 'articlemeta?',
      catalog_id: 'objectId?',
      content: 'objectId?',
      createdAt: 'date?',
      flagged: 'bool?',
      owner_id: 'objectId?',
      rating: 'int?',
      read: 'bool?',
      status: 'string?',
      status_updated_at: 'date?',
      updatedAt: 'date?'
    },
    primaryKey: '_id'
  }


config = {
            schema,
            path: getDBPath(),
            sync: {
              user: app.currentUser,
              partitionValue: new ObjectID(getCatalogId()),
              error: (error) => {
                console.log(error.name, error.message)
              }
            }
        }
        let realm = await Realm.open(config)
        // query
```

I want to query and get the article result and in article schema we have defined a key 'article_meta' which is and objectId. Now I want article result with all the properties with article_meta as an object fetched on the basis of (article.article_meta = articlemeta._id)

Expected result:

```
[{ _id: '1', catalog_id: '', content: '', createdAt: '', main_image_url: '', origin_type: '', pub_date: '', publication: '', sub_title: '', title: '', updatedAt: '', url: '', article_meta: {} }, {..}, {..}]
```

Comment: I may be overlooking it but what is the relationship between those two objects?

Comment: @Jay Thanks for replying. 
article_meta is of type article.
I did this because in the docs they mentioned that there is no need to join(aggregation) two collections. So for that I mentioned a to-one relationship.

Is there any way to join two collection in realm? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Hmm. The `article_meta` property of `article` is of type `article`? That's pretty confusing - how does `articlemeta` fit in? Can you clarify the question? Also, there are no *joins* as such in Realm as it's not a SQL database.

Comment: @Jay It was my mistake I have edited it. Can you now relook into it.
And can you explain a little about relationship that Is it possible to define a relationship and open synced realm instance.Thanks

Comment: There's good info in the  [MongoDB Realm Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/get-started/introduction-mobile/). The issue is not really clear though; what's the correlation between the relationship between those two objects and sync'ing? Do you have an example query (whatever your join is)  you're trying to do that's not working? Can you include your code? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I'm not getting any data to my local realm instance when I'm defining relationship between two schema i.e article and articleMeta
I have added the code that shows how I have created realm instance

Comment: The code and data in the question is unrelated to performing a query (or a 'join'). It's still unclear what's being asked or what the actual issue is. Your above comment says *I'm not getting any data to my local realm* but there's nothing in the question that attempts to get any data from realm - you're just creating a realm instance and nothing more.

Comment: @Jay but when I normally try to open a realm instance with sync configuration I can see my atlas data getting reflected locally, but when I'm doing it defining a relationship I can't see any data. so That's the issue.

Comment: @Jay If you can see my schema's and I want to get data from articles with join of articlemeta.
So do you know how can I achieve this in realm?

Comment: To be clear, there is no 'join' in realm. It's called a query. You need to include what you are querying for in the question. In other words in SQL there's a purpose to perform a join - you don't just do a join for no reason. Same thing here. You want to get certain data from realm so you need to tell us what data you're after.

Comment: @Jay I have added the code and the expected result. Please have a look at it.Thanks

Comment: @Jay, I'm getting this error : "Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property 'article_meta' in class 'article' is of type Link on one side and type ObjectId on the other.". Do you know about this.?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As pointed out in a comment, there is a bit of ambiguity in the question as the text doesn't match the code. The code shows the parent object `article` having a child object `articlemeta` which is generally correct and how relationships are built in Realm. Accessing child objects by querying their objectId is generally unnecessary if the relationship is built in a "Realmy" way as shown in this answer.

-- Original Answer below --

Realm objects can reference 'joined' realm objects via dot notation. from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/examples/read-and-write-data/#filter-queries)

> Filter on Related and Embedded Object Properties
>
> To filter a query based on a property of an embedded object or a
> related object, use dot-notation as if it were in a regular, nested
> object.

So for example, a Person object has a Dog object as one of it's properties and you want to get that pesons' dogs name.

Let's get a specific person by their _id

```
const person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey("Person", 1234)
```

if we then want the persons dogs name

```
const dogName = person.dog.dog_name
```

In your case you can get a specific article, and then access all of the articlemeta properties using dot notation

```
const article = realm.objectForPrimaryKey("article", 1234)
```

and then access the rest of the properties through dot notiation

```
const id = article._id
const catalogId = article.catalog_id
const mainImageUrl = article.article_meta.main_image_url
```

As you can see, a query is not needed (for this example) as the Realm objects know their own child properties and can be accessed via dot notation.

Comment: i think he means what happens if article has a foreign reference key to another object and you'd want to 'join' them. like if Owner has an array of Dog IDs, you'd want realm to return an array of Dogs instead of Dog Ids

Comment: @darrenz Thanks for the comment. This question was from a couple of years ago and there there was a bit of ambiguity so the answer attempts to provide clarity. A couple of things to note: Even though the text states the article_meta is an ObjectId, it isn't, and is defined as an `articlemeta` object, which it should be. So the text is inaccurate, the code is spot on. Also, Realm has little need for foreign keys because objects are used to build forward and backward relationships. It's more efficient as it avoids additional queries as related child data can be retrieved via dot notation.